# How to use HostPath in kubernetes baremetal?

Tags: kubernetes

For **persistant volume** in `kubernetes` i can use `HostPath` .
But my problem is if one of my pods is restarted and created in other node.

How can i handle this?
I am in **baremetal envinroment**.

should i use **NFS**?

Answer (score 1):

As @P Ekambaram has already commented in the last comment below his answer, you might consider to use `nodeSelector` within your Pods by specifying the corresponded label to achieve scheduling Pods on specific Nodes, or via more comprehesive method by adapting `nodeAffinity` which conceptually brings the same approach but with more flexible options: like `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` and `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`. You can find out more relative information in the official Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use nfs shares for your baremetal cluster.

Comment: if i do not use NFS what should i do?

Comment: Simple approach is to add a label to a specific node. And use node selector or node affinity  to get pod scheduled onto that note